# "Mieux vaut être seul que mal accompagné" (Gringore)

Tags: citations

Je cherche la référence exacte du proverbe "Mieux vaut être seul que mal accompagné", communément attribué à [Pierre Gringore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Gringore). Mes connaissances très imprécises en [moyen français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyen_fran%C3%A7ais) me font dire que la phrase devrait ressembler à "Mieulx vault estre seul que mal accompagne(?)" dans le texte original, mais je ne trouve nulle trace de ces mots.
Toute aide serait la bienvenue !

---

I am looking for the exact reference of the proverb "Better to be alone than badly accompanied", commonly attributed to [Pierre Gringore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Gringore). My very imprecise knowledge of [Middle French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyen_fran%C3%A7ais) makes me say that the sentence should look like "Mieulx vault estre seul que mal accompagne(?)" in the original text, but I can't find any trace of these words.
Any help would be welcome!

---

---

addendum : in a book of French proverbs of [1550](https://books.google.fr/books?id=bcZcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22Mieulx+vault+estre+seul%22+-accompagn%C3%A9+-%C3%AAtre+-rester+-Etre&source=bl&ots=UFvHkvWSgj&sig=ACfU3U2OGfItWn0dzTO35YDkJ0youi9mIA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi95KSXr5vsAhUny4UKHWKrCDQQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Mieulx%20vault%20estre%20seul%22%20-accompagn%C3%A9%20-%C3%AAtre%20-rester%20-Etre&f=false) the proverb was printed as follows : "Mieulx vault estre seul que mal accompaigné."
This sentence doesn't seem to be a verse, (it could be a [décasyllabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decasyllable) but it contains 11 syllables; another book has the following decasyllabic text : "Mieulx vault estre seul que mal compaigné"), but at first it resembles a proverb: use of the (gnomic) ["présent de vérité générale"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicatif_pr%C3%A9sent_en_fran%C3%A7ais), two-part structure, opposition between two terms (seul/compaigne).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'après *Bibliothèque de l'École des Chartes*, p 585, un manuscript de 1429 provenant du fond de la reine au Vatican contient le proverbe:

> *[**Il vaut mieulx estre seul que estre mal acompaigné.**](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k12435d/f595.item.r=%22Il%20vault%20mieux%20estre%20seul%20que%20estre%20mal%20acompaign%C3%A9%22)*

La paternité du proverbe ne pourrait donc pas être attribuée à Pierre Gringore (1475-1539).